# scrolling uitableview dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to make a 'UiTableView' which scolls its cells dynamically to the down direction or up direction with and add the next cells to the tableview from the array.

Please suggest me good example over this.

Thanks Neha

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
- (IBAction)clickAction:(id)sender
{
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

or :

```
// (change n to whatever you like)
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:n inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                            animated:YES];
```

if you need something more complex let us know.

Comment: hi shishi thnx for ur reply.... i want that table records should be added and table cells should shift to the downword direction and next record should be added automatically

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet you can scroll and select row table even if rows has not been loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
  [_table selectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:YES 
                                scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```